# Find where an error has occured in R

Tags: r, debugging, error-handling, rstudio

I am running a script in Rstudio and get the following error which is specific to my code saying (The warnings presumably come from the initial error):

```
Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, mon, n, value = 0) : subscript out of bounds
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

I tried searching through my script with ctrl+F for this but it seems that this is not in the script. I tried using `traceback()` and got `No traceback available` I tried running the script through the R shell in `source(filepath)` with `error(options=recover)` and get the following menu:

```
Enter a frame number, or 0 to exit   

1: source("C:\\Users\\Patrick\\Google Drive\\FIDS\\MESc\\Thesis\\KNN-CADv4\\RModel\\Analysis_UI_modified.r")
2: withVisible(eval(ei, envir))
3: eval(ei, envir)
4: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
```

But I'm not sure what to do with this. I've been going through a lot of different answers on SO and tried what they have mentioned above but still am not able to resolve this. Why does these seem to be such a problem with R?

Are there any steps I can follow to find which line in my script this error corresponds to (without manually going through every single line obviously...)? I normally use Python and Matlab and I can usually get the line where the error occurs and take care of what needs fixing but it seems like this isn't trivial with R. The error itself is obvious but I need to know where this is.

Here's the R I'm working with on Windows 7:

```
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10) -- "Spring Dance"
Copyright (C) 2014 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
```

Comment: construct a dummy function consisting of your code/script, call the function and then try `traceback`, it should point you to the source of error

Comment: @Osssan I did as you mentioned `finderror<- function(){ 'Where script is' return(0)}` ran the function in the console and got the same error. Tried `traceback` and got this `1: finderror()`. Still no line numbers is seems. Even if I got something that shows what the line looks like then I could easily search for it in the script

Answer (score 3):

That sign post up ahead .... you have entered ... The BrowserZone:

```
 ?browser   # read the controls documentation
```

Then do an SO search on: `[r] browser debug`

If you run the function after setting the debug flag with `debug('func_name")` then the browser shoud tell you on which line the error was thrown. Other options: When this was an early question on SO, Shane suggested:

```
options(error = quote({dump.frames(to.file=TRUE); q()}))
```

There is the capacity to set breakpoints and to recover code at a particular line number that has particular code although I don't think that gets you exactly what you want, either.

```
?findLineNum
?setBreakpoint   # both on same page.
```

If you are building a package you may benefit by setting the environment variable: 
R_KEEP_PKG_SOURCE=yes

Somewhere you have created a 'mon' variable. Look for code that assigns an object or a column named 'mon' to a value.

Comment: the browser and debug functions have been helpful. However the only information I get for the error is the same as described in the question. mon is a counter variable used to iterate through many arrays in a loop. In one of the arrays the index is out of bounds which causes the error. There's other ways I can find the error I just wanted to see if there was something more convenient